# Draw circle in xml in android

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to display my layout via android xml.

Here's what I want to do:

[image]

I have **12 buttons** with a animals image like this one: [image] , and the circle is the background.

I do not have any idea related to this, how should I start? 
Please give me some suggestion so I can go ahead. What things should I use to do this?

Comment: Seems a lot easier to use a picture and coordinates somehow, but maybe that's just me...(still xml, yeah, but I got the feeling you were looking for some kind of custom super layout)

Comment: @Keyser: could you please post some sample code?

Comment: No, not really. I've only done it once, 1.5 years ago or so. But I bet there are examples to be found

Answer (score 5):

You'd be looking for making a custom view. A good place to start is, as always, android's own development site: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do this with xml. this need simple mathematic calculation that you can not do in xml.
you most extend View class and create your own View. then you can use it in xml.